# Removing an association using related entity id in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Doctrine 2 documentation states that:

> Removing an association between two entities is similarly
>   straight-forward. There are two strategies to do so, by key and by
>   element.

What's the meaning of "by key"? It's the `id` field of the related entity or simply the *position* of the related entity in the collection? For example here `$ithComment` is used (that is the *position* of the comment):

```
// Remove by Key
$user->getComments()->remove($ithComment);
$comment->setAuthor(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the position of the related entity in the collection. On inspecting ArrayCollection..

```
public function add($value)
{
    $this->_elements[] = $value;
    return true;
}

public function remove($key)
{
    if (isset($this->_elements[$key])) {
        $removed = $this->_elements[$key];
        unset($this->_elements[$key]);

        return $removed;
    }

    return null;
}
```

You can see no reference to the collection items identifier is used.

Answer (score 0):

According to Doctrine2 API, a Doctrine Collection's remove method,

> "Removes the element at the specified index from the collection"

(see https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Collection.php#L78)

My conclusion is that the key you're talking about is indeed the position of the related entity.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution, maybe is good for you:

```
public function addSectors(ArrayCollection $sectors)
{
    foreach($sectors as $k => $sector) {
        $this->addSector($sector);
    }
}    

public function removeSectors($sectors)
{   
    foreach($sectors as $k => $sector) {
        unset($this->sectors[$k]);
    }
}
```